# how to display JLabels in separate lines? JavaX GUI

Tags: java, swing

I would like to display my output in the GUI like the picture below

[image: wanted display]

But I end up having it like this when I use `setText` on `JLabel`s

[image: my program:( display]

Here are the codes that display my texts:

```java
class StudentPanel extends JPanel {
    JLabel jlName;
    JLabel jlTitle;
    JLabel jlImageFile;
    JLabel jlGroup;
    JLabel jlDemoWhat;

    private JLabel student1image_2;

    public StudentPanel() {

        //jlName = new JTextArea("<html><body><\n>");
        jlName = new JLabel();
        add(jlName);

        jlTitle = new JLabel();
        add(jlTitle);

        jlImageFile = new JLabel();
        add(jlImageFile);

        jlGroup = new JLabel();
        add(jlGroup);

        jlDemoWhat = new JLabel();
        add(jlDemoWhat);
    }

    public void setStudent(Student s) {
        jlName.setText("Hi Prof, I am " + s.getName());
        jlTitle.setText("I am a " + s.getTitle());
        ImageIcon student1image = new ImageIcon(s.getImageFile());
        Image student1image_1 = student1image.getImage();
        Image student1Resized = student1image_1.getScaledInstance(260, 180, UNDEFINED_CONDITION);
        student1image = new ImageIcon(student1Resized);
        student1image_2 = new JLabel(student1image);
        add(student1image_2);

        jlGroup.setText(s.getGroup());
        jlDemoWhat.setText(s.getDemoWhat());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to separate them?
Thank you so much.

I Googled but so far no hope is found.

Comment: Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: @g00se omg im sorry! im new to coding so im abit blur. ive changed it into codes!!

Comment: Your JPanel has a default `FlowLayout`.  You could try using a [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) with 1 column and zero rows.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc okie! ill try!!!

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc it doesnt work:( it says GridLayout cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: What IDE are you using and which Java version are you using?

Comment: It looks like at one time you were going to go for a more direct approach and use `JTextPane`. Why didn't you?

Comment: @Abra im using visual studios and my jdk version  is  19.0.1 .

Comment: @g00se ooohhh let me try!!!!

Comment: Just leave it for now. *Second* line of `StudentPanel()`, do `setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ctor, `StudentPanel()`, you can set a vertical layout with

`setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));`
before you add your components.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Your code wasn't runnable, so I created this GUI.

[image: Example]

A Swing application should always start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

You use Swing components.  The only reason to extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is when you want to override one or more of the class methods.

I hard-coded the student values.  You would need to add the references to your Student class.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class StudentGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new StudentGUI());
    }

    JLabel jlName;
    JLabel jlTitle;
    JLabel jlImageFile;
    JLabel jlGroup;
    JLabel jlDemoWhat;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addValues();

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));

        jlName = new JLabel();
        panel.add(jlName);

        jlTitle = new JLabel();
        panel.add(jlTitle);

        jlImageFile = new JLabel();
        panel.add(jlImageFile);

        jlGroup = new JLabel();
        panel.add(jlGroup);

        jlDemoWhat = new JLabel();
        panel.add(jlDemoWhat);

        return panel;
    }
    
    private void addValues() {
        jlName.setText("Hi Prof, I am " + "Heng 2");
        jlTitle.setText("I am a " + "Full Time Student");
        jlGroup.setText("I am from group T05");
        jlDemoWhat.setText("I wish to demo Assignment 2");
    }

}
```

Comment: ooooo! thank you so muchhhhhhh!! Ive learned something new today hehe